# How to zip each folder in the directory into a separate .zip archive in python?

Tags: python, zip

For example, there is a directory D:\test\flo with 3 folders Test4, Test67, Test8. (each folder also has files)

As a result, we need to get in the directory D:\test\zip files Test4.zip, Test67.zip, Test8.zip

I tried to use the zipfile module and os.
I do not understand how to do: The name of the archive is the name of the folder from which I take the file and how to write the desired file there

Comment: I know how to do it in theory, but I can't do it in practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a directory as follows, where `archive.py` will save the contents of directories under `flo` into a sibling directory `test`, creating it if it doesn't exist:

```
C:.
│   archive.py
│
└───flo
    │   file7.txt
    │
    ├───Test4
    │   │   file1.txt
    │   │   file2.txt
    │   │
    │   └───somedir
    │           file.txt
    │
    ├───Test67
    │       file3.txt
    │       file4.txt
    │
    └───Test8
            file5.txt
            file6.txt
```

archive.py

```py
import zipfile
import pathlib
import os

# Create the test directory if needed
os.makedirs('test', exist_ok=True)

# Iterate directories under "flo"
for directory in pathlib.Path ('flo').glob ('*/'):
    # Open test\<directory>.zip for writing
    with zipfile.ZipFile(pathlib.Path('test') / directory.with_suffix('.zip').name,
                         'w',
                         compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED,  # zlib compression
                         compresslevel=9) as zfile:         # maximum compression
        # Recursively list everything under <directory>
        for item in directory.rglob('*'):
            # Write each item into the archive, using the path relative to <directory>
            # as the name in the archive.
            zfile.write(item, arcname=item.relative_to(directory))
```

Note that `file7.zip` is **not** a directory under `flo`, so won't be archived in this implementation.

Result:

```py
C:.
│   archive.py
│
├───flo
│   │   file7.txt
│   │
│   ├───Test4
│   │   │   file1.txt
│   │   │   file2.txt
│   │   │
│   │   └───somedir
│   │           file.txt
│   │
│   ├───Test67
│   │       file3.txt
│   │       file4.txt
│   │
│   └───Test8
│           file5.txt
│           file6.txt
│
└───test
        Test4.zip
        Test67.zip
        Test8.zip
```

The `.zip` files contain all the content under the corresponding `flo` directory.